# mysql_connect - Connects to ISP rather than remote host

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to run a PHP script to dump some database tables from a remote host.  Rather than connecting to my remote host, the error shows "access denied" with the IP address of my ISP.  I can connect to other remote servers without a problem.  I am also unable to connect using HeidiSQL and MySQL Workbench (access denied also).

Any ideas?

Comment: They mysql server is probably configured to only permit access from localhost.

Comment: The IP address in the error message is the address of the client, not the MySQL server. You need to add grants to the database for this IP.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow for remote connections, you'll need to toggle allowed addresses for access. You'll be able to do this through a control panel associated with your database.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql.ini (if on windows) or mysql.cnf (if on linux) denies remote access to the database server. If you have access to mysql configuration file remove the following line

bind-address = 127.0.0.0

Restart mysql server and you should be good.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers!  I think the simplest thing for me is to upload the script to the server and run it from there, I don't have access to any server config (a connection with HeidiSQL would be nice, so I will talk with the server admin). IT seemed strange to me that the error was pointing to my ISP rather than the host itself... still scratching my head over that one.